# Failed Password Authentication for user 'postgres' on mac

Tags: postgresql

I recently downloaded the graphical install for postgresql 9.4 on my mac and went through the entire setup, even made a password, but when it came to activate the shell no password would work. I tried my system password and the one I set but neither worked.

Everytime I try

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

I get the error

`psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

This is my pg_hba.conf file

`TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
 "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
 Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
 replication privilege.
local   replication     postgres                                md5
host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5`

Comment: Try your own user password.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your psql password
Change local in conf file to: 
`local   all             all                                     trust`

Restart psql server: 
`sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`
Connect as superuser postgres: 
`sudo -u postgres psql`
Change password: 
`ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'newpassword';`
Change back your conf file to: 
`local   all             all                                     md5`

Restart psql server: 
`sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`